# Apollo GraphQL Lambda Handler Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to run Apollo GraphQL server inside my AWS lambda. I'm using the library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@as-integrations/aws-lambda). I'm also using CDK to deploy my lambda and the REST API Gateway.

My infrastructure is as follows:

```
const helloFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, 'lambda', {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "lambda.ts"),
    handler: "handler"
});

new LambdaRestApi(this, 'apigw', {
    handler: helloFunction,
});
```

The lambda implementation is as follows:

```
const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type Query {
  hello: String
}`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => 'world',
    },
};


const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    introspection: true,
})

console.log('###? running lambda')

export const handler = startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(
    server,
    handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventV2RequestHandler(), {
        middleware: [
            async (event) => {
                console.log('###? received event=' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
                return async (result) => {
                    console.log(("###? result=" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)))
                    result
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

When I POST to my endpoint with the appropriate query I get this error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "body": "Cannot read property 'method' of undefined"
}
```

I'm seeing my logging inside the lambda as expected and I can confirm the error is being returned in the 'result' from within startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(). This code is based on the example for the @as-integrations/aws-lambda library. I don't understand why this is failing.

Comment: I have several Apollo GraphQL lambdas running and I don't recognize a single line of the above code except for the *typeDefs*! (this kind of blows my mind) Which version of Apollo server are you using? Are you using the serverless package to deploy?

Comment: I am using "@apollo/server": "^4.3.2" and "@as-integrations/aws-lambda": "^2.0.0".  "aws-cdk": "2.61.1" for deployment. I'm following the instructions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@as-integrations/aws-lambda

Comment: Hey, I'm using the same code, and having issue with API Gateway, when I test from AWS console requests works, but testing from curl I'm getting Forbidden error. Could you share please your cloudformation template? Probably I'm missing something for permissions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Need to use:

```
handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventRequestHandler()
```

Instead of:

```
 handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventV2RequestHandler()
```

So final code is:

```
export const handler = startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(
    server,
    handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventRequestHandler(),
    {
      middleware: [
        async (event) => {
          console.log('###? received event=' + JSON.stringify(event))
        }
      ]
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks ! this worked. Can you explain ?