# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'method') apollo/server 4

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Following the migration guide from `apollo server` - everything seems to start fine. However, when I make any request it says:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'method')
```

This happens when I make requests from the client and also when i try to open the studio at `/graphql` - so it's definitely not the client.

Any suggestions? I wish the error was a bit more descriptive

```
 "graphql": "15.8.0"
 "@apollo/server": "^4.7.1",
 "@as-integrations/aws-lambda": "^2.0.1",
```

[image]

**Edit**: This helps: [Apollo GraphQL Lambda Handler Cannot read property 'method' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75278888/apollo-graphql-lambda-handler-cannot-read-property-method-of-undefined?rq=2)

At least I can reach the studio now so its getting there.